# Google Api and android Oauth INVALID_AUDIENCE error

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth

I am getting a `GoogleAuthException: Unknown error`, while doing a `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken`.

Just before the exception I see

```
GLSUser: GLS error: INVALID_AUDIENCE <email> audience:server:client_id:xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

I have set the SHA1 from my release key , the package name,  to the google api project. (Which by the way is being used successfully for GCM. )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like that should work; here's the scope-init code from my app which does work.

```
private static final String SCOPE = "audience:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID;
```

So it smells to me like there's a problem with the client id.  Remember that

1. You have to have a project with two client ids
2. One is the one for your android app, with the SHA & package & so on
3. The other is for the server side that you're going to send the token off to

It's the client ID from #3 that goes after ...:client_id:

Comment: @Alok....I have run into the same issue. I am using web client_id in audience in endpoints api and also in android audience scope. Still see the same auth error. How did you generate the web client_id? I went to Google APIs console, generated a Client Id for Web applications with redirect uri & javascript origin as blank. Is that correct?

Comment: Another common cause of this is registering the debug certificate hash and testing with release (or vice versa).

Comment: Since when did the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() method start throwing a GoogleAuthException with message "BadUsername" for an email that is not registered on a device, instead of the previous exception IllegalArgumentException with message "Non existing account 'email_address'" ?  
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken(android.content.Context , java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: bro can u pls help, I did all u said above, yet I m getting this error.Do I need to add client-id,scope,audiences for api method also ? I added them in @Api(..) where audience being my web client id.When I call the api method I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of documenting my issue,

I had the same INVALID_AUDIENCE error come back from a Google sign-in through an AWS Mobile Hub generated sample app. A few things to check,

Like Tim Bray notes aboves, make your client id a valid web client id (not Android). But also have an android client id that has both the proper SHA-1 Fingerprint (found in debug.keystore which Android Studio uses to sign debug builds when you click Run) and package name.

NOTE: The package name listed in the AndroidManifest.xml is not always the actual package name. To find the definitive package name, go to the build.gradle file and see the applicationId field. Be sure to input the right package name in the Developers Console when you configure the Android Client Id.

Comment: I was missing having an android client id declared in the console, even though I'm not using it... weird!

Answer (score 0):

Happened to one on my team although it worked ok on my device.
It turned out to be because of a different `debug.keystore` on our eclipse installations.

To solve it we've copied the company's `debug.keystore` file to `~/.android/` 
(this is the dir on a mac, it's different on linux and windows)

Answer (score 0):

Solve this by deleting your debug.keystore found in your .android folder, then run the new project again to generate a new debug.keystore file. 
Then finally generate a new SHA-1 signing-certificate for Google API.

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to set up oAuth authorization screen in your Google API Console.

That was why I got this error