# INVALID_AUDIENCE error with Google OAuth 2.0 API

Tags: android, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-play-services

I am following this [tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) to get auth tokens.

I have both of my client_ids for web server and android device set up but I am getting an INVALID_AUDIENCE error.  I believe this is because I have not generated and signed my APK, instead I am in development.

Is there something special I need to do to test the auth on my device via USB?

I'll go through how I set up my client_ids.

#### Web Server

This was easy all it needed was a URL.

#### Android

This one was a little harder.  I generated that APK certificate (the .jks file).  Then cd to the jdk/bin dir and ran

```
keytool -exportcert -alias occucard -keystore "C:\Users\Shane\AndroidAppKeys\Occucard/occucard.jks" -v -list
```

as the tutorial instructs.  I think this may be the problem.  Since its a development generated apk and not signed with the key.

Side Note: My scope token required for GoogleAuthUtils looks like:

```
"audience:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Api and android Oauth INVALID\_AUDIENCE error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031238/google-api-and-android-oauth-invalid-audience-error)

Comment: I've already looked at that and couldn't get my answer from it.  Doesn't talk about using it in development mode.

Comment: The guide you used doesn't mention development mode or debug anywhere, it's possible to sign non-release packages with a debug key.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to create a third client_id with the debug.keystore SHA1 key.  I ran the command

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Shane\.android/debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

This allowed me to use the client_id in development mode.